# MySQL one row per user depending on maxDate or maxId

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table in MYSQL called enrollments with these fields: id, user,  estimated_date.

The values in this case are:

```
id, user, estimated_date
1, 1, 2015-10-10
2, 1, 2015-10-10
3, 2, 2015-10-20
4, 2, 2015-10-10
```

I want to select one row per user: the one that has the max(estimated_date). But in case the estimated_date is equal has to select the one that has the max(id). In other words... a group by with ordering by estimated_date and id (in this order).

The output should be:

```
2, 1, 2015-10-10
3, 2, 2015-10-20
```

I have this code now:

```
    SELECT * from enrollments m 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT user,
          max(estimated_date) AS maxdate
   FROM enrollments
   GROUP BY user
  ) x ON m.user = x.user
AND m.estimated_date = x.maxdate
```

Could you help me please? I've been searching a lot but I didn't find anything that fits this case... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `INNER JOIN`, just a `ORDER by estimated_date DESC, id DESC` is enough. Here is your query:

```
Select * FROM (
SELECT
  DISTINCT  `id`, `user`, `estimated_date`
FROM
  enrollments  

ORDER by estimated_date DESC, id DESC

  ) as X
  GROUP BY user
```

full fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31799/3